# Interact with every other item in an array, but only one way?

Tags: php

I have an array in PHP.

It may contain for example

```
$array = Array("A","B","C");
```

Is there any easy possibility in PHP to interact (lets say concatenate, for example) every element with another just once and just ONE DIRECTIONAL?

So result would be AB, AC, BC? (This is just simple example, I need it to work on much bigger examples)

Comment: Well, you do have an actual [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in PHP, or you might be able to use [array_reduce()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) for this.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. You are asking for an algorithm to concatenate 2 elements in a forward direction?

Comment: Well, Im implementing the all path finding function. I have an array of point A, B, C. I need to find all unique paths. So its A->B, A->C etc. But i dont need A->A or C->A (I have already A->C)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work for you. It'll loop through the array and grab an element. Then loop through the array again starting at the n + 1 element of the current element (ie. $j). Effectively, in the second loop, you have the first interaction of the two elements and can do what ever you need to do with them.

```
   function test(array $test)
      {
          $ret = [];
          for ($j = 0; $j < count($test); $j++) {
              for ($i = $j + 1; $i < count($test); $i++) {
                  $ret[] = $test[$j] . "->" . $test[$i];
              }
          }
          return $ret;
      }
```

Then

```
test(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']);
```

would produce

```
array(6) {
    [0] => "A->B"
    [1] => "A->C"
    [2] => "A->D"
    [3] => "B->C"
    [4] => "B->D"
    [5] => "C->D"
}
```

For more precise control (ie. you want to distinguish unique names in the test array (eg. `['A', 'B', 'C', 'A']` where `'A'` shouldn't be used twice)), you can make the `$ret` array an associative array and use `$test[$j]` as the key. Then, you can then check if `$test[$j]` exists in `$ret` in the second loop and base your flow on that check.

For example:

```
function test(array $test)
{
    $ret = [];
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($test); $j++) {
        if (!array_key_exists($test[$j], $ret)) {
            for ($i = $j + 1; $i < count($test); $i++) {
                if (!array_key_exists($test[$i], $ret)) {
                    $ret[$test[$j]][] = $test[$j] . "->" . $test[$i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

called with:

```
test(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A']);
```

would produce:

```
array(3) {
  ["A"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "A->B"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "A->C"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "A->D"
  }
  ["B"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "B->C"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "B->D"
  }
  ["C"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "C->D"
  }
}
```

Finally, for a really foolproof method of finding one-directional unique paths:

```
function test(array $test)
{
    $ret = [];
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($test); $j++) {
        $firstElement = $test[$j];
        # if this element doesn't exists as a key in the return array,
        # then we haven't encountered it yet
        if (!array_key_exists($firstElement, $ret)) {
            for ($i = $j + 1; $i < count($test); $i++) {
                $secondElement = $test[$i];

                # shouldn't have a path to itself?
                if ($firstElement === $secondElement) {
                    continue;
                }
                # make sure that the second element doesn't already exist as a key in the
                # return array...in which case we've already encountered this path
                if (!array_key_exists($secondElement, $ret)) {
                    $ret[$firstElement][$secondElement] = $firstElement . "->" . $secondElement;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

called with:

```
test(['A', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B']);
```

would return:

```
array(3) {
    ["A"]=>
        array(3) {
            ["B"]=>
            string(4) "A->B"
            ["D"]=>
            string(4) "A->D"
            ["C"]=>
            string(4) "A->C"
      }
    ["B"]=>
        array(2) {
            ["D"]=>
            string(4) "B->D"
            ["C"]=>
            string(4) "B->C"
        }
    ["D"]=>
        array(1) {
            ["C"]=>
            string(4) "D->C"
       }
  }
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if he wants to do something other than concatenate the two, he just needs to reference $test[$j] and $test[$i]. Solid answer, though, especially for a newcomer :D

Comment: The one other thing that I will say (since you are new) is that as a general rule, answers are better if you explain them better. Don't just offer the solution, explain why that solution works for them.

Comment: having consider you are a new user, Your answer is  awesome!